# Which one is faster? Array Initialization vs. Malloc + Assignment vs. Array of Pointers? (Performance impact with big dimension)

Tags: arrays, c, arm, initialization, malloc

I want to create and initialize an array of 1024 elements, and I'm exploring which way is the most efficient in terms of **execution time**.

I am working with ARM Neon, using arrays of structures like `uint16x4x4_t`, which are
of the form

```c
    typedef struct uint16x4x4_t
    {
        uint16x4_t val[4];
    } uint16x4x4_t;
```

and I have three scenarios:

### **Scenario 1:**

I initialize an array of 1024 elements of `uint16x4x4_t` like

```c
    uint16x4x4_t arrayTest01[1024] = {
        { { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} } },
        { { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} } },
        //... (1020 more times) ...
        { { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} } },
        { { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} } }
    };
```

In this scenario, I access the elements as `arrayTest01[0].val[1][2] = 999`.

### **Scenario 2:**

I create an array of pointers, then allocate memory and finally assign values.

```c
    // First: Create array of pointers
    
    uint16x4x4_t* arrayTest02[1024];
    
    // Second: Allocate all the memory (individual allocation)
    
    arrayTest02[0] = malloc(sizeof(uint16x4x4_t));
    arrayTest02[1] = malloc(sizeof(uint16x4x4_t));
    arrayTest02[2] = malloc(sizeof(uint16x4x4_t));
    //... (all indexes until 1022) ...
    arrayTest02[1023] = malloc(sizeof(uint16x4x4_t));
    
    // Third: Assign values to each array (using dereference)
    
    (*arrayTest02[0]) = (uint16x4x4_t){ {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15}} };
    (*arrayTest02[1]) = (uint16x4x4_t){ {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15}} };
    (*arrayTest02[2]) = (uint16x4x4_t){ {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15}} };
    //... (all indexes until 1022) ...
    (*arrayTest02[1023]) = (uint16x4x4_t){ {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15}} };
```

In this scenario, I access the elements as `(*arrayTest02[0]).val[1][2] = 999`.

### **Scenario 3:**

I create an array of pointers, then create thousands of individual arrays, and I populate the array of pointers with memory addresses.

```c
    // First: Create array of pointers
    
    uint16x4x4_t* arrayTest03[1024];
    
    // Second: Create individual arrays with unique names
    
    uint16x4x4_t arrayTest03_01 = { { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} } };
    uint16x4x4_t arrayTest03_02 = { { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} } };
    uint16x4x4_t arrayTest03_03 = { { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} } };
    // ... (all indexes until 1022) ...
    uint16x4x4_t arrayTest03_1023 = { { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} } };
    
    // Third: Reference all of them to the array of pointers
    
    arrayTest03[0] = &arrayTest03_01;
    arrayTest03[1] = &arrayTest03_02;
    //... (all indexes until 1022) ...
    arrayTest03[1023] = &arrayTest03_1023;
```

In this scenario, I also access the elements as `(*arrayTest03[0]).val[1][2] = 999`.

### Questions

Now my questions:

1. **Which scenario would lead to better execution time?**

I think in terms of execution time it will be (from lower to higher)

`Scenario 1 <= Scenario 3 <= Scenario 2`

mostly because of all the `malloc` s of Scenario 2 and using unique names for so many arrays in Scenario 3, but I'm not sure. Also, I would have to `free` all those allocations, which will impact the total execution time.

2. **Which scenario requires less memory in the whole program?**

I think all of them are pretty similar, but probably

`Scenario 1 <= Scenario 2 <= Scenario 3`

because Scenario 2 doesn't have unique names as Scenario 3. Again not sure.

3. **Which scenario is more scalable?**

I think in this case `Scenario 2` beats the other two, because the variables are saved in the heap (because of malloc), while for the other two scenarios, everything is saved in the stack. If we increase the number from 1024 to a way bigger number (example 999,999), then the stack memory is too small. Is that correct? Or am I missing anything here?

4. **Any suggestion?**

I think `Scenario 1` beats the other two scenarios for when initializing an array, but is there anything additional that I should be careful of?

Comment: _"unique names"_ : you don't need unique names, you need an array of 1022 `uint16x4x4_t`s and a loop instead of 1022 assignment like `arrayTest03[0] = &arrayTest03_01;`, like `for (int i = 0; i < 1022; i++) arrayTest03[i] = &arrayTest03_foo[i]`

Comment: Why don't you race all the scenarios and measure time elapsed for each?

Comment: That is the wrong type: `uint16x8x4_t` That doesn't match the other code.

Comment: If the array is global, then static initialization takes no time - it is loaded as is into the `.data` section from the binary. (unless, it needs to be relocated by the startup code from ROM to RAM.. but it depends on your environment)

Comment: ... but make things `const`.  Static initializes does take time to load the data initially.  For a system with only RAM, `const` will not matter.  For XIP storage, then the `const` is zero cost.  Some many performance question rest on the platform architecture, so the question is difficult to answer.

Comment: Are these arrays a lookup table that is constant or do you want to modify these arrays?

Comment: Scenario 3 is merely a more complex way to do Scenario 1, with additional indirection to boot.  For Scenario 2, where do the values come from?  If they're statically-defined in your code, all you're doing is taking static data that could be used in Scenario 1 and copying it all to the heap with a bunch of `malloc()` calls along the way.

Comment: Measure, don't guess.  Code up each alternative and profile them.  All things being equal option 1 *should* be the fastest and take the least amount of storage and option 2 *should* be the slowest and probably use the most storage, but things often aren't equal.

Comment: @Jabberwocky This is exactly the same problem. If you do `arrayTest03[i] = &arrayTest03_foo[i]`, then how would you initialize the array `arrayTest03_foo[1024]`?

Comment: @Gerhardh Thank you for noticing it, I fixed the original post.

Comment: @Gerhardh Also this is a lookup table, so they will be constant. But they will be populated from data from another array which will have random data.

Comment: @liwuen You still have not provided the *source* of the data.  If the data is hardcoded into your source code, as in your question, **there's absolutely no reason to use option 2** - that just spends time making an extraneous copy of the data in the heap by copying it from static memory.  If the data is already in static memory, **you've posted no reason not to use it directly**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I modified the original question to show that the data is populated from another array.

Comment: @Gerhardh As you correctly pointed out, this is for a lookup table, I added the reference to an outer array.

Comment: Do not modify your question after receiving answers, especially not in a way that invalidates existing answers.  If you find that you have asked a different question than you meant to do, then you can always ask the question you originally meant as a new question.  Rolling back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1. Which scenario would lead to better execution time?**

Scenario 1 is likely to be most efficient for initialization.  If `arrayTest01` has static storage duration then the initialization will be essentially free, but even if it has automatic or thread duration, initialization is probably via the equivalent of a single `memcpy()`.

Scenario 1 is also likely to be the most efficient for subsequent access.  Storage for the array and all its parts will be in one contiguous block (which is cache-friendly), and access will not involve indirection through pointers, other than possibly a single pointer to the overall array itself.

Scenario 2 is likely to be the most expensive for initialization.  All those `malloc()` calls need to be executed at runtime, and `malloc()` is comparatively expensive.  Also, each of the allocated objects needs to be initialized independently, via the equivalent of 1024 `memcpy()`s instead of (probably) zero or one in Scenario 1.

Scenario 2 is also likely to be the most expensive for subsequent access.  The allocated objects are not necessarily contiguous with each other in memory, hence not as cache-friendly as scenario 1, and there are additional pointer loads and indirect accesses relative to scenario 1.

Scenario 3 is likely to be intermediate for initialization. I would expect it to outperform scenario 2 on account of avoiding all the `malloc()`s.  With a clever optimizer, it is conceivable that initialization might be up to as fast as scenario 1.

Scenario 3 should not be any worse than scenario 2 for subsequent access, because the resulting data structures are the same.  However, scenario 3 might benefit from more favorable arrangement of the data in memory, and the optimizer might be able to do a better job on some accesses.  But scenario 3 still involves extra pointer loads and indirect memory accesses relative to scenario 1, so scenario 3 is not likely to afford accesses as efficient as scenario 1 affords.

---

> **2. Which scenario requires less memory in the whole program?**

Scenarios 2 and 3 require storage for a bunch of pointers that Scenario 1 does not require.  Scenario 2 also has some amount of additional overhead in the form of metadata for all the dynamic allocations.  So 1 < 3 < 2.

---

> **3. Which scenario is more scalable?**

This depends on more details than you have presented.  Inasmuch as your remarks suppose stack allocation for at least the top-level array, however, scenario 2 requires the least space for that array itself, and all the rest of the needed storage is dynamically allocated.  Scenario 1 has all the needed memory in one contiguous block, but requires a bit less storage overall.  Scenario 3 has a higher overall storage requirement than scenario 1, and none of it is dynamically allocated.

Thus, if your scaling concern is about the amount of automatically allocated storage required then scenario 2 will scale the best, then scenario 1, then scenario 3.  Do note that most C implementations for stack-based machines provide means to request larger stack sizes than the default, so this particular consideration is unlikely to be relevant if the needed array size is known in advance.  And if the needed array size is *not* known in advance then the question is moot, because scenario 2 would then be the only viable option among the three presented.

On the other hand, if the concern is performance or overall memory required, then see above -- the relative ordering of the three scenarios on those measures is not scale dependent.

---

> **4. Any suggestion?**

As a general rule, I would suggest avoiding dynamic allocation where it is not needed, but I can't say whether dynamic allocation is needed in your case.

I don't see any reason to prefer scenario 3 over scenario 1.

Whether that leaves you at scenario 1, scenario 2, or something altogether different depends on your application's specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
Ignoring SO practice, OP significantly modified the question **after** this answer was posted. I leave it here so the OP may eventually figure out that executable machine instructions do not have knowledge of the source code (struct declarations) that led to their existence. 4 or 16 adjacent uint's are 4 or 16 adjacent uint's... (It's unfortunate that misconceptions and insufficient understanding can lead to DV's.)

OT: Is there some point in trying to make life difficult with an array of structs?

```
uint8_t arr[][4][4] = {
        { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} },
        { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,42} }, // <== NB '42'
        //... (1020 more times) ...
        { {0,1,2,3},{0,     },{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} }, // <== NB '0'
        { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} }
    };
    
int main() {
    arr[1][3][2] = 41; // ****
    for( size_t x = 0; x < sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]; x++ ) {
        putchar( '[' );
        for( size_t y = 0; y < sizeof arr[0]/sizeof arr[0][0]; y++ ) {
            putchar( '[' );
            for( size_t z = 0; z < sizeof arr[0][0]/sizeof arr[0][0][0]; z++ )

                printf( "%d,", arr[x][y][z] ); // <== Simple, no?

            putchar( ']' );
            putchar( ',' );
        }
        putchar( ']' );
        putchar( ',' );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
[[0,1,2,3,],[4,5,6,7,],[8,9,10,11,],[12,13,14,15,],],
[[0,1,2,3,],[4,5,6,7,],[8,9,10,11,],[12,13,41,42,],], <== Note '41 & '42'
[[0,1,2,3,],[0,0,0,0,],[8,9,10,11,],[12,13,14,15,],], <== Note '0's
[[0,1,2,3,],[4,5,6,7,],[8,9,10,11,],[12,13,14,15,],],
```

---

**EDIT:** How to use the above when the calling code must call ARM functions with the right definition

```
typedef uint16_t uint16x4_t[4];

typedef struct uint16x4x4_t {
        uint16x4_t val[4];
} uint16x4x4_t;

// Changed uint8 to uint16 to conform to OP's datatype
uint16_t arr[][4][4] = {
        { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} },
        { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,42} }, // <== NB '42'
        //... (1020 more times) ...
        { {0,1,2,3},{0,     },{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} }, // <== NB '0'
        { {0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15} }
};

void magic_ARM_func( uint16x4x4_t *a ) { // Notice restrictive parameter datatype
    // What will I do with the data today?
    // I dunno...
    // Print it, perhaps...

    putchar( '[' );
    for( size_t y = 0; y < sizeof a->val/sizeof a->val[0]; y++ ) {
        putchar( '[' );
        for( size_t z = 0; z < sizeof a->val[0]/sizeof a->val[0][0]; z++ )
            printf( "%d,", a->val[y][z] ); // <== Simple, no?
        printf( "]," );
    }
    printf( "],\n" );
}

int main() {
    arr[1][3][2] = 41; // **** NOTICE data modification

    for( size_t x = 0; x < sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]; x++ )
        magic_ARM_func( (uint16x4x4_t*) arr[x] );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't need to print the values, I need to use the arrays as a lookup table for subsequent calculations, and the values come from another array calculated in runtime. The need of the `uint16x4x4_t` structure is because later I must use ARM's instruction set, which require it.

Comment: @liwuen Printing is simply to demonstrate functionality. A contiguous group of data elements can be addressed however the code chooses to address them. At runtime, there's nothing special about declarations made in source code. It's up to you. Declaring/using a pointer to the ARM "data framing" structure would work just as well...  Just pointing out that C can make your life (and code) simpler.